# Alternative backup solution for macOS

Tags: backup, nas

I encountered [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/364847/disable-time-machine-auto-cleaning) issue with Time Machine, so I Googled about alternative solutions, but I can't find one that's suitable for my need. I want the following:

Interface: Both command line and GUI that's similar to Time Machine, with optionally verbose output and/or status.

Speed: At least faster than Time Machine. My Synology NAS is connected through CAT 5e which is 1 Gbps (the hard disk (RAID 5) is faster, about 200 mb/s). Time Machine will only achieve about 3~5 mb/s (maybe because it backup on to a Sparse Bundle), and stop (0 kb/s) for almost half of the time.

Utilization of technology: 
1. Listens to fseventsd (which reports which files are modified) for incremental backup, or at least use the fseventsd files (which reports which folders are modified)
2. Utilize hard link (SMB, NFS*), multi-linked directories (HFS+), or cloning (APFS, btrFS) to save space.

*Do they actually support hard link? I know that they support symbolic links.

Comment: I take it you have already looked at Synology's own Cloud Station?  https://www.synology.com/en-us/knowledgebase/DSM/help/DSM/Tutorial/backup_from_computer

Comment: I personally use Carbon Copy Cloner (CCC) to do what you want to do.

Comment: You'll find all the information you need on their website.

Comment: @DaktaMoriamé Thank you very much for your comment! CCC helped me a lot with regards to backup!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Carbon Copy Cloner](https://bombich.com) (CCC). It uses APFS snapshot (when backing up to APFS volume) to preserve backup history. The snapshot (backup history) retention policy can be adjusted manually.

The newest version (CCC 6) brings `fsevents` support, providing much faster incremental backup.

Comment: FYI, CCC is not the only one to support fsevents.  ChronoSync has supported them for years.

Comment: @user128998 Thank you very much for your information!

Comment: I use CCC from ten years. It's the best ;-}